# accessing the value in struts action sent from jquery ajax coming as null

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts

Hi i am new to struts 2 and jquery, i want to access a value in struts action class sent from an ajax call, but when I try to do that I am getting data as null, may any one please guide me.

here is the code

ajax function:

```
var searchURL = url;
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "conversation.action",
        dataType: "text",
        data : searchURL,
        success : function(data)
        {

        };
    });
```

action class:

```
String data;
//getter and setter methods

System.out.println("Data::"+getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'url' holds in your javascript, but it should explicitly have the struts variable name, otherwise Struts has no idea where it should map the url to.

For example, `var searchURL = 'data=www.google.com';` (where '`data`' is the name of the variable in your struts action class)

Other options:

**i)** If your parameters are in a form. You could have passed the complete form data via `$('#formId').serialize()` in the data section of your ajax call.

**ii)** Instead of struts action variable mapping, parse the request parameters in your action. For example, in '`data`' of ajax function, pass `'someUrl=www.google.com'`. In your action class, get the url as `String url = request.getParameter('someUrl')`;